# java.util.concurrentmodificationexception in my application

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, modbus

Help me to find out why the exception is occurring.My application works fine when it starts but after a moment it stops working below is my code is there anything wrong.

```
ModbusTCPTransaction trans = new ModbusTCPTransaction(con);
        Runnable r = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(isRunning){

                    try {

                        Thread.sleep(10);
                        trans.setRequest(req);

                        trans.execute();
                        ReadMultipleRegistersResponse res = (ReadMultipleRegistersResponse) trans.getResponse();
                        tf1.setText(String.valueOf(res.getRegisterValue(0)));
                        tf2.setText(String.valueOf(res.getRegisterValue(1)));
                        tf3.setText(String.valueOf(res.getRegisterValue(2)));
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Modbusconn.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (ModbusSlaveException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Modbusconn.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (ModbusException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Modbusconn.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Modbusconn.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

                    }
                }
            }
        };

            new Thread(r).start();
```

Comment: What's your stacktrace / error log?

Comment: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:386)
 at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:355)
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.shape.PathUtils.configShape(PathUtils.java:45)
 at javafx.scene.shape.Path.impl_configShape(Path.java:251)
 at javafx.scene.shape.Path.impl_configShape(Path.java:89)
 at javafx.scene.shape.Shape.impl_computeGeomBounds(Shape.java:864)